# React Facebook Login with Enzyme mount - TypeError cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, facebook-login

I have a very simple React component which only contains a FacebookLogin component:

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import FacebookLogin from "react-facebook-login"

class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.facebookCallbackResponse = this.facebookCallbackResponse.bind(this)
    }

    facebookCallbackResponse(response) {

        console.log('facebook callback response: ', response)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FacebookLogin
                appId="my_app_id"
                clientToken={"my_client_token"}
                autoLoad={false}
                fields="name,email"
                callback={this.facebookCallbackResponse}
                icon={<i className="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>}
                textButton="Login"/>
        );
    }
}

export default Login
```

I want to test this component with Jest and enzyme mount. This is why I setup my test configurations like:

```
import {configure} from "enzyme"
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16"

configure({adapter : new Adapter()})
```

My **App.test.js** code is below for actual testing:

```
import {mount} from "enzyme"
import Login from "../component/dummy/Login"

describe("Login tests", () => {
    it("Login form incomplete", () => {

        const handleSubmit = jest.fn()
        const facebookCallbackResponse = jest.fn()
        const wrapper = mount(<Login/>)

        const instance = wrapper.instance()
    })
})
```

My **package.json** is:

```
{
  "name": "rental-application",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "1.16.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-compound-slider": "^3.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.7.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-notifications": "^1.7.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-table": "^6.11.4",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run the tests, I receive the following error:

> **Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'parentNode' of undefined
> at E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-facebook-login\dist\facebook-login-with-button.js:1:5116**
> at t.value (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-facebook-login\dist\facebook-login-with-button.js:1:5146)
> at t.value (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-facebook-login\dist\facebook-login-with-button.js:1:3884)
> at commitLifeCycles (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:19814:22)
> at commitLayoutEffects (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:22803:7)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:188:14)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\generated\EventListener.js:26:30)
> at innerInvokeEventListeners (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:318:25)
> at invokeEventListeners (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
> at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
> at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\generated\EventTarget.js:231:34)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:237:16)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:292:31)
> at commitRootImpl (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:22541:9)
> at unstable_runWithPriority (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:12)
> at runWithPriority$1 (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:11039:10)
> at commitRoot (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:22381:3)
> at finishSyncRender (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:21807:3)
> at performSyncWorkOnRoot (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:21793:7)
> at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:21188:7)
> at updateContainer (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24373:3)
> at E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24758:7
> at unbatchedUpdates (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:21903:12)
> at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24757:5)
> at Object.render (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24840:10)
> at fn (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16\src\ReactSixteenAdapter.js:488:26)
> at E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16\src\ReactSixteenAdapter.js:405:37
> at batchedUpdates$1 (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:21856:12)
> at Object.act (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
> at wrapAct (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16\src\ReactSixteenAdapter.js:405:13)
> at Object.render (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16\src\ReactSixteenAdapter.js:474:16)
> at new ReactWrapper (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\enzyme\src\ReactWrapper.js:115:16)
> at mount (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\enzyme\src\mount.js:10:10)
> at Object. (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\src\test\Login.test.js:9:25)
> at Promise.then.completed (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:276:28)
> at new Promise ()
> at callAsyncCircusFn (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:216:10)
> at _callCircusTest (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:212:40)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at _runTest (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:149:3)
> at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:63:9)
> at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:57:9)
> at run (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:25:3)
> at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapterInit.js:176:21)
> at jestAdapter (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapter.js:109:19)
> at runTestInternal (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:380:16)
> at runTest (E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:472:34)

You see the error emanates from facebook login button when I run the tests. However, if I run the application using `npm start` command, everything works. Can you tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the solution. I think I should post here for future reference:

This might be an issue with Facebook Login itself. When you want to use the mount for testing, you need to add a few lines of the following codes into your **setupTests.js** file:

```
const fbScript = document.createElement('script')
fbScript.id = 'facebook-jssdk'
document.body.appendChild(fbScript)
```

As this has been pointed [here](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/issues/217), a dummy `script` element needs to be put into `document.body` before you run tests.

So the **setupTests.js** file finally looks like this:

```
import {configure} from "enzyme"
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16"

configure({adapter : new Adapter()})

const fbScript = document.createElement('script')
fbScript.id = 'facebook-jssdk'
document.body.appendChild(fbScript)
```